# Prove that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \geq abc(a+b+c)$

Tags: inequality

First of all, we use classical inequalities to get:

$\frac{a^4 + b^4}{2} \geq a^2b^2$

$\frac{b^4 + c^4}{2} \geq b^2c^2$

$\frac{c^4 + a^4}{2} \geq c^2a^2$

Adding above inequalities:

$\frac{(a^4 + b^4) + (b^4 + c^4) + (c^4 + a^4)}{2} \geq a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2$

$\Leftrightarrow a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \geq a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2$

I can't get to the other side of inequality: $abc(a+b+c)$

Comment: Now take the quantities on the right, $a^2b^2,b^2c^2,c^2a^2$, and repeat the process.

Comment: would there be another way? and how did you come to that conclusion? could you explain me? @AwnonBhowmik

Answer (score 3):

This is just a direct application of the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), which states that, given the real numbers $x_1\le x_2\le \dots\le x_n$ and $y_1\le y_2\le \dots\le y_n$ and a permutation $\sigma:\{1, 2, \dots, n\}\rightarrow \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, we have
$$x_1y_{\sigma(1)}+x_2y_{\sigma(2)}+\dots+x_ny_{\sigma(n)} \le x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\dots x_ny_n$$
that is, you'll get a greater result if you **agroup the terms with similar size**.

---

For your problem, assume without loss of generality that $a^2\le b^2\le c^2$ and apply the rearrangement inequality to conclude that $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\le a^4+b^4+c^4$.

Notice that you can also prove that $abc(a+b+c) = a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2\le a^2b ^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$ by applying the same inequality to $ab$, $bc$ and $ca$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, apply Jensen inequality and AM-GM inequality: $\dfrac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3} \ge \left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^4 =\dfrac{(a+b+c)}{3}\cdot \dfrac{(a+b+c)^3}{27}\ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)abc}{3}\implies a^4+b^4+c^4 \ge abc(a+b+c)$.